# Agregar Horario de verano

Tags: javascript, json

tengo mi codigo pero no me detecta horarios de verano de algunos paises...

```
const tiempo = (tiempoFormat) => {
let ahora = new Date(),
remaintime = (new Date(tiempoFormat) - ahora + 1000)/1000,
remainsecond = ('0' + Math.floor(remaintime % 60)).slice(-2),
remaiminutes = ('0' + Math.floor(remaintime / 60 % 60)).slice(-2),
remaihours = ('0' + Math.floor(remaintime / 3600 % 24)).slice(-2),
remaidays = Math.floor(remaintime / (3600 * 24));
return{
    remaintime,
    remainsecond,
    remainsecond,
    remaiminutes,
    remaihours,
    remaidays
}
}
```

Alguien me ayuda, por favor

Comment: Puedes usar `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` para conseguir la diferencia horaria.

Comment: me ayudarias, ya intente y no me funciona

Comment: Tienes un ejemplo de lo que quieres hacer? Porque `.getTimezoneOffset()` te va a mostrar  la diferencia horaria en tu zona horaria actual.

Comment: que me muestre la zona horaria... ejemplo 
(GTM-5)
     `${dia(dateEnd.getDay())}, 
                        ${dateEnd.getDate()} de
                        ${mes(dateEnd.getMonth())} -  
                        ${time(dateEnd.getHours())}:${time(dateEnd.getMinutes())}`;